# How to politely ask a customer to close a ticket/incident

Tags: politeness

This is the way I currently phrase it, although I was wondering if it could be improved?

> I am glad to hear that the issue is now solved. Please consider closing this message if you do not have any additional questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, it's quite alright, but a minor change I'd make is:

> I am glad to hear that the issue is now solved. Please consider closing this message ***if you have no further questions***

It flows a bit better this way.